# date format in java

Tags: java

I want to convert Date in different Format.

For example,

String fromDate = "2011-04-22"; 
I want to convert this fromDate as "22nd Apr, 2011"

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a little tricky because of the "nd" in 22nd. Depending on the day it'll need a different suffix. `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support formatting like this. You'll have to write some additional code to get it. Here's an example, however it's limited to working in certain locales like US:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d'__' MMM, yyyy");

String fromDate = "2011-04-22";
Date date = fromFormat.parse(fromDate);
String toDate = toFormat.format(date);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if (day % 10 == 1 && day != 11) {
    toDate = toDate.replaceAll("__", "st");
} else if (day % 10 == 2 && day != 12) {
    toDate = toDate.replaceAll("__", "nd");
} else if (day % 10 == 3 && day != 13) {
    toDate = toDate.replaceAll("__", "rd");
} else {
    toDate = toDate.replaceAll("__", "th");
}

System.out.println(toDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the given format using a `SimpleDateFormat` and then write the 2nd form using a different `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");

Date dat = from.parse("2011-04-22");
System.out.println(to.format(dat));
```

Not sure how to if there is a way to add the 'nd' to '22nd' though.

Answer (score 1):

Following this code to remove ordinal of date. It is running successfully.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class patrn {

    private static String deleteOrdinal(String dateString) {
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)");
        Matcher m = p1.matcher(dateString);
        while (m.find()) {
            dateString = dateString.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group(0)), m.group(1));
        }
        return dateString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateString = "August 21st, 2012";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
        Date emp1joinDate = null;
        try {
            emp1joinDate = sdf.parse(deleteOrdinal(dateString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateString = "2011-04-22";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM, yyyy");

try {
    Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
}
catch(ParseException pe) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that format should depend on Locale... Sure, you can do it like this:

```
String fromDate = "2011-04-22";
DateFormat incomming = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat outgoing = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.Long, Locale.US);
try {
  Date parsed = incomming.parse(fromDate);
  String toDate = outgoing.format(parsed);
}
catch (ParseException pe) {
  pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, instead of Locale.US you need to pass end user's Locale...

BTW. Instead of lousy SimpleDateFormat you might want to use [Apache Commons Lang's](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html). Please also find [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) if you are performing a lot of Date-related operations.

Comment: Outputing in the locale's long format is useful, but not what the OP asked. They gave a very specific output format that they required.

Comment: I know he asked for specific format, which is probably invalid from I18n stand point. Not that Long is, Default should be used...